# Correct answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

https://askubuntu.com/a/1379258/1210606

The answer above was deleted by a mod with the justification:

> The workaround is Windows only!

Either this person doesn't know Wine's folder structure (`drive_c`) and/or doesn't know WineHQ from where the workaround was copied from (and linked to), a single test of the game in question: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28925

Whether or not it works remains to be tested. I didn't test it and I won't. I don't buy Windows games. But in any case, **there's no reason to delete an answer that faithfully reproduces a possible solution found by someone testing it and having experienced the same problem as the OP**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer started with "Total War: Rome 2 is Windows only software. "  Based on that, and the fact that the path you specified "drive_c/users//Application Data/The Creative Assembly/Rome2/scripts/preferences.script.txt" with the exception of "drive_c", led to the closing of the question, which was an over sight on my end, and I do apologize for that.

Comment: No worries, mate. For the record, it's how Wine works. "drive_c" is found inside .wine. It's like this probably to emulate the Windows folder tree the software expects to find.

Comment: +1 this is the kind of classy, respectable mea culpa that we should all emulate when we make mistakes...which, as humans, we all inevitably do.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about that. I've undeleted your answer which seems to be on point, and in any case seems to have been deleted based on a misunderstanding as you say.